# Spark uses Scala version 2.11.8 but installed 2.11.7

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jvm

Installed Spark version 2.0.2

Installed Scala version 2.11.7

When running `spark-shell` I get:

> Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java
>   1.8.0_74)

When running `util.Properties.versionString` in Scala I get:

> res0: String = version 2.11.7

Where is the disconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spark shell uses its own version of the REPL and its packaged libraries. So, there is no interaction between the installed scala shell and the spark-shell.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to change Scala version that Spark RELP is using?

Comment: Not very easily, why?